# How to do Basic Auth on Openshift Websockets and Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, authentication, websocket, openshift

In my regular Openshift Tomcat7 cartridge, I have a websocket endpoint up and running. Clients can connect and interact (on [Port 8000](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/)). 
Now I wanted to do some Basic Auth on the websockets, so that only authenticated clients can connect to the websocket.

But when I add the according `<web-resource-collection>` (which works on other URLs), it dows not affect the websocket endpoint.

The part of my web.xml looks like:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>auth</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/autharea/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>wsauth</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern> <!-- websockets are here-->
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Basic Authentication</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

An echo server is annotated like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/echo")
public class EchoServer {
   ....
}
```

Locally, authentication works like a charm (So I *guess* it is the rerouting to port 8000 that hits me here).
Is there any way to configure Tomcat to also do basic auth on websockets in Openshift?